# python how to cleanup a subprocess

Tags: python

I'm running a python script that will restart a subprocess every 2 hours. code as follow.

```
import datetime
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        with subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/script.py']) as p:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            try:
                print(f'starting the process at {p.pid}')
                p.communicate(timeout=4800)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                print('timeout terminate process')
                os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
                p.terminate()
                p.wait(60)
                p.kill()

            dif = datetime.datetime.now()-start_time
            t = 4810-dif.total_seconds()
            print(f'restarting after {t/60} mins')
            time.sleep(t)
```

in my script.py, I'm having a thread executor that each thread runs a chrome webdriver instance. The issue I'm having is when the process timeout, the python process is terminated but all the webdriver instances are still lingering. Is there a way for the parent process to kill all the spawned child processes aka the chrome driver instances in my case? Running on my mac

Edit:
script.py

```
def run_with_config(user):
  i = WebDriverInstance()
    try:
        return i.run_loop() # while true infinite loop running some ui actions
    except Exception:
        return False
    finally:
        i.quit()

def run(users):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(user_configs)) as executor:
        f_to_user = {}
        for c in user_configs:
            f = executor.submit(run_with_config, c)
            f_to_user[f] = c
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(f_to_user):
            res = f.result()
            print(res)
```

Comment: Could you share the `script.py` file? I think that the solution depends on how you spawn the child processes.

Comment: added the basics of script.py

Comment: What is `WebDriverInstance`? Does it come from a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` to subprocess popen works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the subprocess in a new process group, then kill the entire group with `os.killpg()`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        with subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/script.py'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP) as p:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            try:
                print(f'starting the process at {p.pid}')
                p.communicate(timeout=4800)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                print('timeout terminate process')
                os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
                p.terminate()
                p.wait(60)
                p.kill()

            dif = datetime.datetime.now()-start_time
            t = 4810-dif.total_seconds()
            print(f'restarting after {t/60} mins')
            time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: This is windows only flag. Any mac/unix version?

Comment: Oops, didn't realize. I don't see anything similar.

Comment: I tried with just `os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)`, but it kills the restart.py script as well, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Right, subprocess.Popen doesn't create a new process group on Unix.